# udp 300 - acl drop - flow is denied

Tags: cisco-asa, l2tp

I am facing below issue after connecting l2tp with  Cisco asa.
Split tunnel is configured.

It drops dhcp packets. Here is capture and config.
29: 22:39:38.733909       192.168.255.1.68 > 255.255.255.255.67:  udp 300 Drop-reason: (acl-drop) Flow is denied by configured rule
  54: 22:39:41.731041       192.168.255.1.68 > 255.255.255.255.67:  udp 300 Drop-reason: (acl-drop) Flow is denied by configured rule.

Config >> sh run access-list
-> access-list MY_ACL extended permit udp any any range bootps bootpc

Config >> sh run access-group
-> access-group MY_ACL in interface outside control-plane
-> access-group MY_ACL in interface outside